# Using mongo queries to return new json structure

Tags: json, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Currently playing around with aggregation filters to group results by sessionID. Is it possible to change this in the database:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("xxx"),
  "quizId" : "xxx",
  "sessionId" : "xxx",
  "questionId" : "xxx",
  "categoryId" : "xxx",
  "question" : "text here",
  "answer" : "male",
  "created" : ISODate("2015-12-04T12:19:43.050Z"),
  "__v" : 0
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("xxx"),
  "quizId" : "xxx",
  "sessionId" : "xxx",
  "questionId" : "xxx",
  "categoryId" : "xxx",
  "question" : "another text here",
  "answer" : "25",
  "created" : ISODate("2015-12-04T12:19:43.050Z"),
  "__v" : 0
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("xxx"),
  "quizId" : "xxx",
  "sessionId" : "xxx",
  "questionId" : "xxx",
  "categoryId" : "xxx",
  "question" : "first question text here",
  "answer" : "answer A",
  "created" : ISODate("2015-12-04T12:19:43.050Z"),
  "__v" : 0
} // several questions more with same session ID//
```

to return this after a MongoDb query:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("xxx"),
  "quizId" : "12345",
  "sessionId" : "xxx",
  "Gender" : "male",
  "Age" : "25",
  "Q1" : "answer A",
  // These aggregated from other objects with same sessionId
  "Q2" : "answer D",
  "Q3" : "answer C"
}
```

Comment: Answer a is present in the sample docs. From where are you getting answer c and d?

Comment: You can get  answer A,C,D... in a array using $group and $addToSet. However you can use $project to get expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of user3632894, i grouped answers by sessionID using

```
db.questionanswers.aggregate( 
  [ 
    { $group : { _id : {sessionId: "$sessionId" }, answer: {$addToSet: "$answer"} } }
  ]
)
```

Which returns

```
{
  "sessionId" : "xxx",
  "answer" : [
    "0" : "answer A",
    "1" : "answer D",
    "2" : "answer C"
  ]
}
```